# Dart => expr syntax only an expression not a statement is partial

Tags: dart

Dart => expr syntax notes:

> Only an expression—not a statement—can appear between the arrow (=>) and the semicolon (;).

case:

```
sayHello(String name) => print("Hello, $name");
```

Here I think print is a statement.

Generally we agree:

- Expression: which can be calculated as a value.
- Statement: a piece of code which can do logic processing.

=> can be understood as a **single-line function**, a expression or a single-line statement(Function Expression).

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if ...`, `for ...`, `switch ...`, would be statements. `print()` is a function call that evaluates to `void` and is an expression as `a + b` which is also a function call like `a.operator+(b)` just with a different syntax.

Comment: a+b arithmetic expression

Comment: Yes, but also a function call as explained in my answer. The `+` operator is a method on the `num` (and `int`, `double`) class. It's just a different way of writing. A function call is not a statement.

Comment: Thanks, A function call is not a statement. Very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Summary => expr:

- Arithmetic Expression: `a + b`
- Assignment Expression: `a = b`
- Relational Expression: `a > b`
- Logical Expression: `a && b`
- Conditional Expression: `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3`
- Function Expression: `print()`